# angular2 CLI HTTP not found error

Tags: angular, angular-http, angular-cli

I've created a new angular2 application using the [angular-cli](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli). Now I was trying to get the data from an API using **HTTP**. The code I've written:

**movies.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Movie } from './movie';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/Rx';
```

My atom editor gives error on `@angular/http` line. So, I've manually installed `angular2` using `npm install angular2` on my project folder and then modify that error generated line like this:

```
import { Http, Response } from 'angular2/http';
```

BUt now my console is showing:

> "NetworkError: 404 Not Found -
>   http://localhost:4200/angular2/http/index.js"

I've added in my **index.html** page the following script:

```
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.17/http.dev.js"></script>
```

and in my **package.json** files dependencies `"angular2": "2.0.0-beta.17",`.
still the same error.

Anyone have any clue? I'm a newbie in angular2. So, any help or suggestion is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you mixed beta version and rc version.

In beta versions, there are some bundled JS files that preregisters modules by name. Something like that:

```
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.min.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/http.min.js"></script>
```

In this case, there is no need for custom configuration for Angular2 modules in SystemJS:

```
<script>
  System.config({
    packages: {      
      app: {
        format: 'register',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    }
  });
</script>
```

With rc version, Angular2 don't provide this (yet) and you need to configure explicitly SystemJS for Angular2 modules:

```
var map = {
  'app':                        'app', // 'dist',
  'rxjs':                       'node_modules/rxjs',
  'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'node_modules/angular2-in-memory-web-api',
  '@angular':                   'node_modules/@angular'
};

var packages = {
  'app':                        { main: 'main.js',  defaultExtension: 'js' },
  'rxjs':                       { defaultExtension: 'js' },
  'angular2-in-memory-web-api': { defaultExtension: 'js' },
};

var packageNames = [
  '@angular/common',
  '@angular/compiler',
  '@angular/core',
  '@angular/http',
  '@angular/platform-browser',
  '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic',
  '@angular/router',
  '@angular/router-deprecated',
  '@angular/testing',
  '@angular/upgrade',
];

packageNames.forEach(function(pkgName) {
  packages[pkgName] = { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
});

var config = {
  map: map,
  packages: packages
}

if (global.filterSystemConfig) { global.filterSystemConfig(config); }

System.config(config);
```

Comment: I've added the `packageNames` manually on my `system-config.ts` file. also edited my `app` and `packages` variable according to your answer. But now the error is `Cannot GET /main`

Comment: `main` is the module you initially import? If so you need to have this: `System.import('app/main')`. And the `main.ts` file located under the `app` folder...

Comment: Sorry, i didn't get your last comment properly.

Comment: No worries! With the configuration above, you need to have your TypeScript files under the `app` folder. See `'app': { main: 'main.js',  defaultExtension: 'js' },`. Otherwise SystemJS doesn't apply the `defaultExtension` configuration and try to use `/main` instead of `/app/main.js` to load your module... Hope it's clearer ;-)

Comment: Sorry to disturb you again. http://postimg.org/image/m8rnj1u4h/ from this image you can see my `ts` files are under my app folder and my `system-config.ts` file contents. based on this config the error is: `"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:4200/app/main.js"`

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are not using beta version of angular2
So  open  package.json and add this line under the dependencies

```
"@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.1",
```

Then open the terminal and type

```
npm install
```

It will update your system-config.ts with

```
const barrels: string[] = [
  // Angular specific barrels.
  '@angular/core',
  '@angular/common',
  '@angular/compiler',
  '@angular/http',
  '@angular/router',
  '@angular/platform-browser',
  '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic',

  // Thirdparty barrels.
  'rxjs',

  // App specific barrels.
  'app',
  'app/shared',
  'app/tree',
  'app/tree/item',
  /** @cli-barrel */
];
```

where it was

```
const barrels: string[] = [
  // Angular specific barrels.
  '@angular/core',
  '@angular/common',
  '@angular/compiler',
  '@angular/router',
  '@angular/platform-browser',
  '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic',

  // Thirdparty barrels.
  'rxjs',

  // App specific barrels.
  'app',
  'app/shared',
  'app/tree',
  'app/tree/item',
  /** @cli-barrel */
];
```

So now you can use

```
'@angular/http'
```

instead of

```
 'angular2/http'
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the RC version of angular2 and not the beta.17.As far as I know, The import from `@angular` is introduced in the RC version.

In this version, they splited the angular2 in multiple packages. This means that, you need to add multiple packages in your `package.json`.

```
"@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.1",
"@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.1",
"@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.1",
"@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.1",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.1",
"@angular/router": "2.0.0-rc.1",
"@angular/router-deprecated": "2.0.0-rc.1",
"@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.1"
```

---

**NOTE**

I have not tested it, but it's working fine to me.

Comment: I've changed the `package.json` file as you told me. but same result. Then I tried to install the version `2.0.0-rc.1` using `npm install angular2@2.0.0-rc.1`, then it gave me `No compatible version found: angular2@2.0.0-rc.1`

Comment: @Emu Take a look at my note. I'm sorry, but I didn't had time to upgrade my own application so far.